# ScrollView must hold only 1 direct child exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, illegalstateexception

I get the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

This is my layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_listgrey"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_listgrey" >

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/rl1">

            <ImageView
               />

            <TextView
                />

            <TextView
               />

            <TextView
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/rl2"" >

            <ImageView
                 />

            <TextView
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The same layout worked fine in case of an Activity. Where as it gives the exception when using in a **Fragment**.

**MainActivity:**

```
FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
t.add(R.id.frame, new mFragment());
t.commit();
```

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Bit if i wrap this ScrollView in a FragmeLayout, it works fine.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_listgrey" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
.......
.......
.......
</ScrollView>
</FramLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The same layout worked fine in case of an Activity. Where as it gives
>   the exception when using in a Fragment.

The layout will work just fine as the content view for an `Activity`(but try to add another view to the `ScrollView` and see how it goes;) ) and it will work as well for a `Fragment`, you just don't use it well. This:

```
t.add(R.id.frame, new mFragment());
```

will add the `Fragment's` view(the one created in `onCreate`) to the `ScrollView`(the `ScrollView` has the id `R.id.frame`), meaning that you'll have two views in the `ScrollView`(which is not allowed): the `RelativeLayout` and the root of the `Fragment`'s view. The `addView` methods of the `ScrollView` class will check to enforce that you end up with a single child in the `ScrollView`.

> Bit if i wrap this ScrollView in a FragmeLayout, it works fine.

This is normal as you add the `Fragment`'s  view to the parent `FrameLayout` and not to the `ScrollView`.